# Does Canonical have other deals with companies like the Amazon search feature?

Tags: canonical

I was interested to find out if Canonical, the producers of Ubuntu, have other financial dealings for integrated features of their operating system, other than the controversial Amazon search feature?

How else is funding for Ubuntu achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question (reasons below):

1. It's [open-source](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/our-philosophy) so it doesn't need much funding considering the community contributes a lot of coding time - nearly all Ubuntu packages are based nearly entirely on community-made code (essentially everything other than Unity, the Ubuntu Software Centre and some patches for some applications to work better with Unity).
2. [Donations](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/questions?distro=desktop&bits=32&release=lts) on download. Since you can just download it free anyway this probably doesn't raise much.
3. Canonical's paid services to companies ([Ubuntu Advantage/Landscape](http://www.ubuntu.com/management)) including [Google](http://www.zdnet.com/the-truth-about-goobuntu-googles-in-house-desktop-ubuntu-linux-7000003462/), these help because they cost a lot and the overflow from this goes to Ubuntu.
4. Presumably royalties (support costs etc...) from the [Ubuntu Phone](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that most Ubuntu code is created inhouse, and big projects like MySQL, VirtualBox etc are mostly done by big companies like Oracle, IBM, etc. Donations - I bet that most people download the software for free, and I can't imagine that much money comes in via download donations. But like Redhat, paid services will probably account for most of the funding, and then the agreements with Google or Amazon.

Comment: @SPRBRN I agree, I wrote that answer quite a while back when I was very idealist! I'm much more pragmatic now. You're right, I still think Ubuntu are making a loss probably because they make most money through their paid services especially to companies. They do benefit a ton through open-source however since all they need to do on the desktop is maintain the Unity 7 shell (and the Ubuntu Software Centre), distribute all the packages, keep them updated etc... However, the actual software itself (the hard work in my opinion) are done by the community.